# how do i fix the error spl_autoload_register():Argument has been ignored

Tags: php, model-view-controller, spl-autoload-register

i get this error from my index page that is the only view page in the Model View Controller(MVC)
project i have and with the code below in my index page

```
<?php 

define("ROOT", dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("APP",ROOT . "app" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("VIEW", ROOT . "app". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "view" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("MODEL",ROOT . "app" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "model" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("DATA", ROOT . "app" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "data" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("CORE" , ROOT . "app" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "core" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("CONTROLLER", ROOT . "app" .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "controller" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);


$modules = [ROOT,APP,CORE,CONTROLLER,DATA];



$path = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR .implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$modules));

spl_autoload_register("spl_autoload", false);
```

Comment: Can you add the actual error that you are seeing? It seems to be missing in the question

Answer (score 2):

As [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#126119) on the PHP manual says:

> Since PHP 8.0 spl_autoload_register() will always throw a TypeError on invalid arguments, therefore the second argument `throw` is ignored and a notice will be emitted if it is set to False.

So on PHP 8 you should no longer pass `false` as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
spl_autoload_register("spl_autoload", false);
```

with

```
spl_autoload_register("spl_autoload");
```

[Link to documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use the default `spl_autoload()` implementation, I would suggest passing `null` as the first argument as per PHP documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#refsect1-function.spl-autoload-register-parameters